# International investing and currency fluctuations

Tags: etf, mutual-funds, currency, international, foreign-currency

Lets suppose a British investor has some participations (say, for a value of £10000) in a Britih (**not hedged**) fund or ETF whose underlying assets are in US dollars, but that is denominated in pounds sterling.

If the pound sterling goes down with respect to the dollar, will that make the fund/ETF's value go up in the same proportion?

if not, how does this work? I'm aware that a fund manager needs to convert from pounds to dollars and, if the investor sells, then he/she will need to convert the dollars back in pounds, so if the pound has lose value this change should be more beneficial, am I missing something?

What would happen with hedged ETFs/funds?

Comment: @base64 I think yes, but that post specifically speaks about UCITS ETFs. Can that explanation be 100% applied to mutual funds? What about non-UCITS ETFs?

Comment: Yes the fund will move in "same proportion" as the currency. Yes the fund manager converts your money on your behalf. Forex market has bid ask spread of 0.01%. The behaviour would be the same for other products, only the agents and participants are different.

Comment: Be aware if the Fund Class does not contain "GBP", it means the Bank or introducer doing the conversion at horrible rates.

Comment: @base64 after reading the link you have provided, I have realized that this behaviour will be different in the case of hedged ETFs/funds, so I have added this question to my original post. Do you know how that work for the hedged ones?

Comment: For hedged funds, you will lose/gain interest rate differentials, which is the difference between interest rates of Federal Reserve and Bank of England. Hedged products are achieved using Futures. See https://money.stackexchange.com/a/121949/24920 for a similar mechanism.

Comment: @base64 please can you explain what do you mean by the fund contains 'GBP'? You mean the fund contains it in its name, right? My understanding was that, if the fund contains "GPB", that only means that it is denominated in pounds sterling, therefore the conversion is made by the fund managers. Does this mean that the conversion will be better than in the typical bank? For intance, this fund: https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-us-equity-index-fund-accumulation-shares?intcmpgn=equityusa_usequityindexfund_fund_link contains the "GBP" (see NAV), right?

Comment: Yes as long as the word GBP appears in the KIID Fund Issuer's website, the money is converted at near 0.01% cost. https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/rs/gre/gls/1.3.0/documents/1272/gb